# db Table/view not found when running jar in ubuntu

Tags: java, eclipse

I try to connect to an embedded derby db using a java program. it works well on windows 10 and when i run it from eclipse in ubuntu but when i run the jar in terminal it throws:

```
"java.sql.SQL.SintaxErrorException:Table/View 'REGISTRATION' does not exist."
```

Do i need to set something in ubuntu to make it work?

```
....................................................
    public class JDBC {
................................................
static Connection conn = null;
    ............................................  
 try{
     Driver derbyEmbeddedDriver = new EmbeddedDriver();
     DriverManager.registerDriver(derbyEmbeddedDriver);
    String dbURL = "jdbc:derby:MyDB;create=true";
    System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database...");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL);
    System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");

 }catch(SQLException se){
    se.printStackTrace();
 }catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
 }
................................................................

        JButton btnLogin = new JButton("Login");
     btnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            try { 
                String query="select * from REGISTRATION where NUME=? and PRENUME=?";
               PreparedStatement pst=conn.prepareStatement(query);
               pst.setString(1, textField.getText());
               pst.setString(2, passwordField.getText());
               ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();
               int count=0;
               while(rs.next()){
                   count=count+1;
               }
               if (count == 1 )
               {
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Conectat");
                       }
               else 
               {
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Nume sau parola gresite!");
                       }
               rs.close();
               pst.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
                }

            }

    });

btnLogin.setBounds(25, 182, 117, 25);
frame.getContentPane().add(btnLogin);
.................................................................
```

Comment: Cause "Table/View 'REGISTRATION'" to exist?

Comment: the table is there. it finds the NUME and PRENUME and works just fine when i run the jar in windows10 or in ubuntu from eclipse. the exception is thrown ONLY when i run the jar from ubuntu